# Server path in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, path

I have a problem with reading a file from a Windows service that is on an other computer on the network.

If I have a file locally I just give the path for example.. `C:\test\`

I just write `C:\\Test\\` and it works great, but on the server with this address `\\\Server\Test\`

I don't know what to write... I would love some help!

/Nick

Comment: Shouldn't it be \\Server\C$\Test\ ???

Comment: @DimiToulakis - As long as there is a share called `C$`.  It all depends on the sharing setting that Nick3 has or has not set up on the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for:

```
string myPath = @"\\Server\Test";
```

or:

```
string myPath = "\\\\Server\\Test";
```

This doesn't seem to be anything related to SQL-Server, and is just a simple C# string question.

In general you just replace `\` with `\\` so if there's normally two `\` next to each-other in the path (such as `\\server`) you want to then have `\\\\`

Answer (score 0):

If it is a windows local machine Windows try to change the folder (x86), i have the same problem some time ago and for some reason is not working in the default folder x86., or if is a SQL server take a look at this [post](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q272705&SD=MSKB&).

Don't forget that you need to create the file `\Test` in folder `\\Server` in order to access it.